# how to get order word with lxml in python?

Tags: python, lxml

I use lxml to get text in the html content like below:

```
a = '<span class="p_show">testa1:<a title="xxxx" href="/drama/MnJXVQ==">testa2</a></span>'
b = '<span class="p_show"><a title="xxxx" href="/drama/JFxhX2Nv">testb</a>1:testb2</span>'
```

code here:

```
from lxml import etree
html = etree.HTML(a) 
a1 = html.xpath('//span/text()')[0]
a2 = html.xpath('//span/a/text()')[0]
res = a1 + a2
```

res  is what i want,but for b situation,i got the reverse result, could u plz help me to deal this ?thanks for all of here!

Answer (score 0):

```
from lxml import etree 
html = etree.HTML(a)  
a = html.xpath('//span//text()') 
res = ''.join(a)
```

it's the solution working for me!